# Parsing POST request body containing file content

Tags: http, go, post

I compose an HTTP request to send file content:

```golang
// HTTP request.
req, err := UploadRequest("/slice", "file", pth)
```

By this function:

```golang
// Creates a new file upload http request.
// https://gist.github.com/mattetti/5914158/f4d1393d83ebedc682a3c8e7bdc6b49670083b84
func UploadRequest(uri string, paramName, path string) (*http.Request, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path) // handle err...
    fileContents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file) // handle err...
    fi, err := file.Stat() // handle err...
    file.Close()

    body := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(paramName, fi.Name()) // handle err...
    part.Write(fileContents)

    err = writer.Close() // handle err...

    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    return request, err
}
```

## Question

The request handler receives the request body:

```golang
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) // I have request body :)
    }
}
```

Debugger shows the request `body` is:

[image]

I'm trying to get the body data after `\r\n\r\n` characters. How can I do that?

## Tried

This is tried, but didn't work:

```golang
err = r.ParseForm() // Handle err...
stl := r.PostForm.Get("file") // "file" param name is hard-coded.

// `stl` is just an empty string.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Request.FormFile](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.FormFile) to parse the multipart request body and return the file within:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        f, h, err := r.FormFile(paramName)
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
    }
}
```